# ApplicationUserManager - UserManager throwing exception on creating new user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the default ASP.net 'Register' method to create a new user from another controller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> SyncNewUsers()
    {
            RegisterViewModel register = new RegisterViewModel();
            register.UserName = item.entity_name;
            register.Email = item.fields.preferred_email;
            register.MobilePhone = item.fields.preferred_phone;
            register.Password = "IT@test123";
            register.ConfirmPassword = "IT@test123";
            register.Role = "Admin";
                await new AccountController().RegisterNewUser(register);

            return View();
    }
```

My 'Register' method:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterNewUser(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.MobilePhone };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Role);

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);



                return RedirectToAction("newxpusers", "Users");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

However, it never gets further than `var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);` where I get the error: *'UserManager' threw an exception of type 'system.nullreferenceexception'*

I would assume it's got something to do with the HttpContext in the UserManager, but I am unsure how to deal with this when I am passing the Model to this method on the fly, rather than through a standard form submission.

Comment: Why would you do that ? I mean hard code user to create in controller ? I'm doing like [this](https://github.com/Awesome-CMS-Core/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Entities/Data/SeedData.cs) to seed data to db

Comment: I am not hardcoding a user, that top/first method gets its user details from an API call, hence no user input needed.

Comment: May I know the reason why you have to create user like SyncNewUsers ?

Comment: Because the API call will fetch new users from another system automatically, so I want the user accounts to create at the same time.

Comment: Then why you dont seed user into db first like my recommend ?

Comment: I read your post, but I do not see how that is relevant to what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up bypassing `UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);` by implementing the following:

```
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know am probaby late but for posterities sake. I had the same error and I realised it was the password requirements after all. Make sure:

1. **It contains a number**
2. **It contains a special character**
3. **It is 8 characters long**

After doing this the record was inserted into the database so i suggest you make or check the password requirements before sending the form.